# (WooCommerce) Conflict with template – Can’t load payment methods

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates

Thank you for your attention. I’m desperate for some help…
I’m facing some harsh issues with my template and WooCommerce…

I’m using Apus Realia RealState Template, and at first, a payment gateway module (e.Rede) conflicted with the template. I thought the conflict was restricted to the module, but I found out the conflict is with WooCommerce.
The console shows me nothing relevant…

What to do when your payment methods box does not load fully (it loads, but it maintains thta preloader wheel overlaying/blocking the box), because the template is not compatible with WooCommerce?
Is there any classes or functions or any method or process I gotta do, so WooCommerce allows me to finish my payment?

Everything I mentioned does not happen with any other template activated. I’ve already increased PHP memory.

Comment: I'm REALLY desperate :/

Answer (score 0):

Issues like this may be caused by either a conflict with your theme or with another plugin. You can read more about plugin and theme conflicts in the documentation here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-self-service-guide/

The best way to determine if the issue is being caused by a theme and/or plugin is to do the following:

1. Temporarily switch your theme back to the [Storefront](https://www.woocommerce.com/storefront/) Theme.
2. Disable all plugins except for WooCommerce - you can try to leave Rede enabled, though I don’t have experience with it. Temporarily enabling PayPal or Stripe which are built in seem to be better options for testing at first to see if the box loads.
3. Test to see if the issue has been resolved.

If that resolves the issue, then slowly re-enable features until you find the one that's causing the conflict.